# Span's style doesn't align horizontal on Android Phone

Tags: android, html, css

I've worked on a website http://ineland.se and when my client views it on her phone (Samsung Galaxy S6) she gets this issue with the mobile-nav button (three horizontal bars):
[image]

Now the weird thing is that I can't find this issue replicated anywhere else. I do not have access to an Samsung Galaxy S6 (I'm just a small business developer) and when I use http://browserling.com to check the issue, it looks normal.

Here's the HTML for the icon:

```
<span id="header-burger" class="burger-nav btn">
        <span class="burger-nav-symbol open-burger">
            <span class="dash">&mdash;</span>
            <span class="dash to-cross">
                    <span class="plain">&mdash;</span>
                    <span class="cross x1">&mdash;</span>
                    <span class="cross x2">&mdash;</span>
            </span>
            <span class="dash">&mdash;</span>
        </span>
    </span>
```

Css (sass) for the symbol:

```
.burger-nav-symbol {
            position: relative;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            padding: 2px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            * {
                clear: both;
            }

            .dash {
                display: block;
                float: left;
                color: $dark_A;
                overflow: visible;
                @include transition ($trans_all, $trans_time, $transease, $trans_delay);

                &.to-cross {
                    position: relative;
                    z-index: 14000;

                    .cross {
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 0;
                        left: 0;
                        opacity: 1;
                        @include transition ($trans_all, $trans_time, $transease, $trans_delay);

                        &.x1 {
                        opacity: 0;
                            }
                        &.x2 {
                            opacity: 1;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, I've noticed that your question still hasn't a marked solution. Is this because you simply forgot or is your question still unanswered? I'd be happy to help you further with your case, otherwhise please mark this question as solved as it helps other users for a better experience on stackoverflow.

Comment: I think I forgot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried debugging your website in chrome (by making the viewport smaller) and it looked like this [image: This is what it looks like]

When I used the inspector mode i saw this code:

[image: This is what i saw]

after I removed that weird square it looked fine.

This is not an answer, but maybe you should try to find out how to get rid of that square.

Comment: Thanks this looks like a possible cause!

Comment: Let me know if you could fix it with that information

Comment: This was the issue, however it only showed in Chrome on windows / on android for me. So weird.

Comment: I'm glad i could help